# Def Generate_dummies for object to numeric variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with 28 object variables and I want to do One Hot Encoding to convert them to numeric. I use this function but it doesn't work

```
def generate_dummies(dataframe, variable_name):
    _dummy_dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataframe[variable_name], prefix=variable_name)
    dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, _dummy_dataset], axis=1)
    dataframe.drop(variable_name, axis=1, inplace=True)
    return dataframe

for i in df.select_dtypes(include = object).'cate_columns':
    df = generate_dummies(df,i)
```

I put all my object variables into a list called cate_columns

Comment: Please take a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you this time).

Answer (score 0):

`get_dummies` is only applied to columns that have the `dtype == object`, so there is no need to go one by one. You can also restrict the columns you want by setting `columns` parameter:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = cate_columns)
df.drop(columsn = cate_columns, inplace=True)
```